# Background colour not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, background, background-color

Hey, I have noticed that when using Internet Explorer my websites background completely disappears, I am not doing anything different to what I useually do so does anyone have any ides of what could be going on? I think it may have something to do with either the use of HTML5 elements or the Blueprint CSS framework. The site can be found [here](http://flowdev.co.uk/). In all other browsers it looks fine.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE <9 doesn't support HTML5 so your page will be rendered differently in IE<9 but here's a fix for you :)

[HTML5 enabling script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/)

Comment: Thanks! I have seen this one a long time ago and forgot about it, I am going to include it in my library because I use it in every site I make. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a HTML5 shim to help IE (and a few others) recognise the elements. You'll also need to tell the browser that they are block level elements by default.

[Here is the result](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/200907/Blog/HTML-5-Browser-Test/) of my browser test:

You can grab my [JavaScript file here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cms/engine/scripts/html5.js) (by creating the elements in script, the browser then accepts any elements with the same tag) - it is already minified and needs to be in the HEAD of your document (in case you normally put them at the bottom of your document):

And you will need to add this CSS to the top of your style sheet:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

I've tested the fix on tons of browsers as you can see in the test and have been running my website using this fix for ages!

Comment: I have already done the CSS fix, so this needs to be used in conjunction with your JS?

Comment: Yeah - the JavaScript actually helps browsers that don't know about the new elements to understand them.